# Flutter Firebase Realtime Database get the Object Key in Query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to FLutter and learning it to my own. I want to get the object key using the query from Firebase Realtime Database as highlighted in below screen shot:
[image]

My Query Method is:

```
void queryDB(BuildContext context) async {
    AppUtil.showLoader(context: context);
    String userId = "u1";
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('usersnode/users').orderByChild('userId').equalTo("u1").get().then((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        print("KEY:::" + snapshot.key);
       
      } else {
        print('No data available.1');
      }
      AppUtil.dismissLoader(context: context);
     
    });
  }
```

It always print **users** but my expectation is to get **0**

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop inside the snapshot, for example:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('usersnode/users').orderByChild('userId').equalTo("u1").get().then((snapshot) {
 if (snapshot.exists) {
   Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
    values.forEach((key, value) {
      print(key);
   }); 
  } else {
    print('No data available.1');
 }
});
```

After looping, you should be able to access both `0` and `1` by using the `key` property inside the `forEach()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
List<String> _listKeys = [];
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('shop/products').get().then((snapshot) {
 if (snapshot.exists) {
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key, value) {
      _listKeys.add(key)
    }); 
  }
});
```